# how to split column of table in select command in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

i have column in one table with string value than string value splited with ','

my table is like this:

```
id        strColumn
1         abc,def,egh,asa,plok
```

I want the character string to be separated using the split function when placed in the selection command and placed in a table as follows

```
newColumn
abc
def
egh
asa
plok
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Poor you. Who's idea was it to store comma separated items? That will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: it is sqlserver

Comment: This functional is heavy dependent on SQL Server version(below is the query for SQL Server 2016 and later)

Comment: sql sever introduces `STRING_SPLIT` in 2016 and later version. make sure you have 2016 SSMS and database compatibility level is set to 130 or above

Comment: my sqlserver version is v18.4

Comment: please show the output select @@version;

Comment: 18.4 is the version of your Sql Server Management Studio; SQLServer is currently version 15 (SQL2019) - dude..

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0):

```
USE tempdb
GO

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Test',N'U')IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE tempdb..#Test;
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
 ID TINYINT NOT NULL,
 StrColumn VARCHAR(50)
)
INSERT #Test(ID,StrColumn)
   VALUES(1,'abc,def,egh,asa,plok');

 SELECT T.ID,VALUE
 FROM #Test AS T
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(StrColumn, ',');

  DROP TABLE #Test;
```

Fro SQL Server 2016 and later you can use STRING_SPLIT-function (example is above)